# How to let the program show the words after using dictionary?

Tags: c#

I am using `Windows Form Application`, in the application, there is two rich `Textbox` and one `Button`, I want the `RichTextbox` 2 to display `RichTextbox` 1 after using the `Dictionary`.How to do that?What is the code for the `Button`?

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Dictionary<char, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<char, string>();
    dictionary.Add('a', "%");
    dictionary.Add('A'," %");
    dictionary.Add('b', " &");
    dictionary.Add('B', " &");
    dictionary.Add('c', " <");
    dictionary.Add('C', " <");
}

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    second_richtextbox=  (???)
}
```

So that when I type cab it will translate to "<%&"
I want to translate the letter to different symbol.

Comment: What if the user enters a character that isn't in the dictionary?

Comment: The user will get back the words he/she types

Comment: just an example:  cab="<%&"   ,   def="def"     , please help me

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could do it, using LINQ:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    second_richtextbox.Text = string.Join("",
        first_richtextbox.Text
            .Select(ch => 
                dictionary.ContainsKey(ch) ? dictionary[ch] : ch.ToString()));
}
```

Or a more straightforward way using a loop and `StringBuilder` (I'd probably do it this way):

```
var result = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < first_richtextbox.Text.Length; i++)
{
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(text[i]))
    {
        result.Append(dictionary[text[i]]);
    }
    else 
    {
        result.Append(text[i]);
    }
}

second_richtextbox.Text = result.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code on your Click Event of Button

```
 string frstvalue = richTextBox1.Text;
        string finalvalue = "";
        char[] a = richTextBox1.Text.ToArray();
        foreach (char c in a)
        {
            if (dictionary.ContainsKey(c))
            { 
                string value = dictionary[c];
                finalvalue += value;
            }
        }
        richTextBox2.Text = finalvalue;
```

I hope it will help